# Vue CLI 3 prerender-spa-plugin displaying blank pages and same index.html

Tags: javascript, vue.js, single-page-application, prerender

I've run "npm run build" and the output of my file folders are the following:
[image]

Then if I dig in deeper, all the page folders have an index.html file containing:
[image]

The code for my vue.config.js and the prerender-spa-plugin is:

```js
const path = require('path');
const PrerenderSPAPlugin = require('prerender-spa-plugin');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');


module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './public/index.html',
        inject: false
      }),
      new PrerenderSPAPlugin({
        staticDir: path.join(__dirname, './dist'),
        routes: ['/', '/om-guldbaek', '/aktiviteter', '/foreninger', '/begivenheder', '/gdpr', '/institutioner', '/login', '/nyheder', '/kontakt', '/registreringer'],
      })
    ],
  },
};
```

When I publish the website to Netlify with GitHub I get a blank website with no errors in the console. If it helps you can go to: https://guldbaekby.netlify.com

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: Check the [example](https://github.com/chrisvfritz/prerender-spa-plugin/blob/master/examples/vue2-webpack-router/webpack.config.js), I don't see `renderer: new Renderer({...` in your example, not sure if that's needed

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. If I add this option it will run during development, and it will open a new window with all the defined routes displaying blank pages

Comment: In the example there is a check `if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {`, so that it doesn't load `PrerenderSPAPlugin` on dev